# Analisador Léxico usando o LEX

Tags: c, c++, analise-léxica

Estou usando o gerador LEX para fazer uma analise léxica de um simples código em C++. O seguinte código é do gerador:

```
%{
    #include<stdio.h>
%}

extern FILE *yyin;

%%
"<"         {printf("(Identifier, %s)\n",&yytext[0]);}
">"         {printf("(Identifier, %s)\n",&yytext[0]);}
"+"         {printf("operador de soma %s\n",&yytext[0]);}
"-"         {printf("operador de subtracao %s\n",&yytext[0]);}
%%

int yywrap(){
    return 1;
}

    int main(){

        yyin=fopen("cpp.cpp","r");

        yylex();
        fclose(yyin);   
        return;
    }
```

Como podem perceber, usei a variável 'yyin' para chamar o arquivo cpp.cpp para fazer à análise léxica. Gostaria de ao invés de printar, o texto fosse escrito no arquivo cpp.cpp. Ou seja, o resultado para cada lexema fosse escrito no próprio código analisado. Arquivo cpp:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int a = 0;
    int b = 2;
    int c = a + b;

    cout << c << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

*Sei que tem lexemas que não serão encontrados pela gramática, mas é só um exemplo para explicar que eu quero que os lexemas encontrados sejam escrito dentro do arquivo cpp.cpp(como se ao invés da função 'printf' fosse uma função fprintf - que escreve em um arquivo, usando C, ou um RETURN para que eu possa escrever no arquivo dentro do método main).

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa escrever no final do arquivo ? ou pode sobrescrevê-lo ?
se você estiver usando o linux e puder sobrescrever o arquivo cpp.cpp faça o seguinte.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

    yyin=fopen(argv[1],"r");

    yylex();
    fclose(yyin);   
    return 0;
}
```

E quuando executar abra o terminal com ctrl+alt+t e faça ./executavel < cpp.cpp

Comment: Se eu quiser usar outro arquivo para escrever ? Eu vi uma função 'yyout', mas não sei utiliza-la. Poderia descrever como seria o uso dela?

Comment: O yyout é a saída padrão do Lex, você pode fazer yyout = stdout, me dê um exemplo de como você gostaria que fosse a saída do seu programa, eu tenho um projeto incompleto, talvez possa ajudar :https://github.com/CarlosPereira27/Compiladores_TP/blob/master/lex/c_minus.l

Comment: Minha dúvida é, como gerar os tokens (o lex gera automaticamente ou eu que gero qualquer numero ?), como escrever a tabela de símbolos em um arquivo de saída, que seria justamente pelo yyout. Tenho esse código e quero gerar uma tabela de símbolos a partir de dele para o arquivo simbTables.txt lendo o arquivo cpp.cpp (arquivo contem qualquer coisa, é so para testes) como eu escreveria a tabela de símbolos e instalava o ID para todos os tokens ?

Comment: Bem fiz um código aqui e funciona, faça o seguinte :`%{
    #include<stdio.h>
%}

extern FILE *yyin;

%%
"<"         {fprintf(yyout,"(Identifier, %s)\n",yytext);}
">"         {fprintf(yyout,"(Identifier, %s)\n",yytext);}
"+"         {fprintf(yyout,"operador de soma %s\n",yytext);}
"-"         {fprintf(yyout,"operador de subtracao %s\n",yytext);}
%%

int yywrap(){
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

        yyin=fopen("code.cpp","r");
 yyout=fopen("saida.txt", "w");
        yylex();
        fclose(yyin);   
 fclose(yyout);
        return 0;
}`